# How to move a local MySql database on a remote server

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration

I have a question about mysql db. I created the site locally and now want to move it to the server. I have created websites. Doing import and export of the database, but now I have a problem. Previously, I always enjoyed the various panels of access (admin). But now the provider gave me only the name & password of the database and ftp. I do not have any control panel (for example cPanel) and I do not understand how to work with the database now.
Thanks for any help

Comment: MySQLdump howto: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Comment: I had the same query and this question helped me a lot thanks. +1 from me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) has a nice graphical interface for administration of MySQL databases.

Comment: tnx! how to connect with db? pls. I think I speak not all the information.

Comment: i create new connection. but host are not allowed. I enter the host is the same as the host of the FTP. is it right?

Comment: The MySQL server usually has a different hostname. If it's not the same as the FPT you will need to get it from the provider

Comment: Thank you for help me in my question. Now I'm on the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a GUI program to access the database and work with it, since it will make the transition much easier if you're used to using a control panel. You can get GUI clients that run as programs on your computer, instead of running on the remote server as cPanel and phpMyAdmin do. This means that they will work regardless of the provider if you have the username and password.

There's many MySQL front-ends out there, but two I would recommend are the official [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) if you're running Windows or Linux, and [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) if you're running Mac (MySQL Workbench can also run on Mac, but I personally prefer Sequel Pro). Both are free.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin is a tool that you could install on the web server, and if you install it, you could then import the data that you've exported from your local database.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Alternatively, and I'm guessing the answer to this is "no" but I'll throw it out there anyway, do you have SSH access to the server at all?  If so, you could just cat the file and import it straight in to your database.